# When does the MSVC compiler/linker synthesize scalar/vector deleting destructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

When working with an existing project, having made some modifications to some external libraries, I am encountering issues of the following kind when building a library dependent upon another dynamically-linked library:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl Foo::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl Foo::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)

If I run `dumpbin /symbols` on the offending `.obj` file I can clearly see these symbols as `UNDEF`.

What is interesting to me is that there are no complaints of other undefined symbols, and the destructor for `Foo` is not referenced at all in the object file symbol dump. The main references to these synthesized functions that I can find on StackOverflow are from people who have not defined their destructor, however I can clearly see `Foo::Foo` being exported from the library where `Foo` is defined (by running `dumpbin /exports` on the `.lib`).

This brings me to the core of my question: When does Visual Studio (2015) choose to synthesize these functions, and when does it decide that they should be linked from another translation unit?

Comment: Have you checked the [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)? No guarantee that it helps but it exists for a reason...

Comment: I trust VS synthesizes those always when new Foo and/or new Foo[x] is somewhere in code.

Comment: @HansPassant `Foo` does not declare any user-defined `operator delete` or `operator delete[]`. Moreover, other libraries which use `Foo` (and indeed call `new Foo`/`delete Foo`) do not have any problem linking against the library containing Foo.

Comment: To the person who voted to close - I described my problem for background information. My question is not asking for "debugging help", I am simply asking when MSVC synthesizes these functions. :)

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same behavior in VS2019 in our project. However in VS2022 (as well as GCC and Clang) the same code compiles/links just fine.

To me (and to answer the question), **this is a compiler bug in VS2019 (and below?)** and in our scenario (where Foo has a few base classes with lots of 'virtualness' involved) it was caused by

```
// Foo.h
~Foo() = default;   //< the culprit
```

However, **any** of these two **workarounds** fixed it:

- Explicitly declaring the DTor in the header (definition in `foo.cpp` did NOT help):

  ```
  // Foo.h
  ~Foo() {};
  ```
- Using (at least one) of the missing operators in the CPP which refuses to link:

  ```
  // Foo.h
  ~Foo() = default;

  // Other.cpp
  void bar()
  {
    auto p = new Foo();
    delete p;
  }
  ```